# should changing partition size affect the output of a query?

Tags: apache-spark

I am practicing some examples from a book on `Spark`. In of of the examples, I read some data from `.csv` files

```
val staticDataFrame = spark.read.format("csv")
.option("header", "true")
.option("inferSchema", "true")
.load("/data/retail-data/by-day/*.csv")
```

then create an `sql` view

```
staticDataFrame.createOrReplaceTempView("retail_data")
val staticSchema = staticDataFrame.schema
```

then run a query

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{window, column, desc, col}
staticDataFrame
.selectExpr(
"CustomerId",
"(UnitPrice * Quantity) as total_cost",
"InvoiceDate")
.groupBy(
col("CustomerId"), window(col("InvoiceDate"), "1 day"))
.sum("total_cost")
.show(5)
```

I get the following output

```
+----------+--------------------+-----------------+
|CustomerId|              window|  sum(total_cost)|
+----------+--------------------+-----------------+
|   16057.0|[2011-12-05 00:00...|            -37.6|
|   14126.0|[2011-11-29 00:00...|643.6300000000001|
|   13500.0|[2011-11-16 00:00...|497.9700000000001|
|   17160.0|[2011-11-08 00:00...|516.8499999999999|
|   15608.0|[2011-11-11 00:00...|            122.4|
+----------+--------------------+-----------------+
```

then I changed the partition size and ran the same query again. But I got different output

```
    scala> spark.conf.set("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions","5");

scala> staticDataFrame.
     | selectExpr(
     | "CustomerId",
     | "(UnitPrice * Quantity) as total_cost",
     | "InvoiceDate").
     | groupBy(
     | col("CustomerId"),window(col("InvoiceDate"),"1 day")).
     | sum("total_cost").
     | show(5)


+----------+--------------------+------------------+
|CustomerId|              window|   sum(total_cost)|
+----------+--------------------+------------------+
|   14075.0|[2011-12-05 00:00...|316.78000000000003|
|   18180.0|[2011-12-05 00:00...|            310.73|
|   15358.0|[2011-12-05 00:00...| 830.0600000000003|
|   15392.0|[2011-12-05 00:00...|304.40999999999997|
|   15290.0|[2011-12-05 00:00...|263.02000000000004|
+----------+--------------------+------------------+
only showing top 5 rows
```

Is this expected behavior. Should the output be the same in both cases?

Answer (score 1):

How many records does your dataframe has? it doesn't matter though.

I believe It is behaving as expected, since you are showing just 5 records, Your second query returning different set of data after partition.

try sorting on some column and get first 5 results, it should give you the same results before and after partition.

Thanks